# Change a synced AD user's Username

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-office-365, entra-id

We have a user called John Smith, his username is a local AD user called John.Smith@alpha.com - this is synced with AD connect to microsoft 365.
We have a cloud shared email address called John.Smith@bravo.com.  Where John.Smith@alpha.com is a delegate user.

Alpha.com is no longer a company so John.Smith@alpha.com now needs to become a shared email address.  John.Smith@bravo.com needs to become the main username for John.  Both email addresses need to continue working.

In the cloud I converted John.Smith@bravo.com to a regular mailbox, and converted John.Smith@alpha.com to a shared mailbox.  In AD, I changed John Smith's email address and username to John.Smith@bravo.com - there were no proxy addresses showing in attribute editor.  AD Connect reported errors and the Office 365 webpage would say the username still was John.Smith@alpha.com.  After this didn't work I also tried changing proxy addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it does not seem possible solely from AD or 365 admin centre.  Here's a workaround I did.

I had to get the user's computer and use desktop Outlook to ensure the emails are not lost.

1. `Outlook` Export the shared mailbox (John.Smith@bravo.com) to a pst file (ensure offline files are all synced, Outlook defaults to 1 year)
2. `365-Admin` Delete shared mailbox
3. `AD` Change username and email in AD (from alpha to bravo)
4. `AD` Perform AD Connect delta sync (or wait for sync)
5. `User PC` Clear Office credentials from user's computer via control panel (and logout from anything else they may be logged into)
6. `Outlook` Login to Outlook - We are now logging in as John.Smith@bravo.com, but it will fetch all their emails that were sent to John.Smith@alpha.com
7. `365-Admin` Create new shared mailbox John.Smith@alpha.com and assign the recently changed John.Smith@bravo.com as delegate
8. `Outlook` Once Outlook has synced all emails/items, drag/move all emails (inc. sent) to shared mailbox
9. `Outlook` When complete, import pst file into main account

This will take a while for emails to sync with the cloud.

Once you delete the shared mailbox, that pst file is the only place where the user's email are saved.  Put it somewhere safe.  It can be deleted onces everything has completed and synced with the cloud.